# window.location.href to subfolder

Tags: javascript, html, href, window.location

I tried to set the location via js on a button click event:

```
 onclick="window.location.href='shop/checkout'"
```

being on the "shop" page, this onclick event leads me to `/shop/shop/checkout`. using

```
onclick="window.location.href='checkout'"
```

leads me to `/checkout`, which is slightly confusing, because the href target wasn't the root directory...

however, I tried "./shop/checkout", "./checkout", "/shop/checkout", "/checkout"....nothing seems to work ... i'm starting to feel rather stupid...

---

The path itself isn't really a physical directory tough; it gets rewritten and passed to a content management system, which prepares the page. So the path has to be "/shop/checkout/" or "/shop/checkout".

---

[EDIT] it's the freaking content manager. i have to work around this another way -.-

Comment: Your problem is quite weird... but what happened when you tested with `/shop/checkout`?

Comment: it leads to `/shop/shop/checkout`

Comment: by the way, same results if i use `window.location=` or `window.location.href=` ...i think i will just go with ´domain.tld/shop/checkout´ but it's still weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried

```
onclick="location.href += 'checkout';"
```

?

Comment: Oh, sorry, it will work ok when you are on the shop page only, give me a few minutes, I'll write full code

Comment: same results...but i found the error somewhere else (editing)

Comment: `location.href.indexOf('shop')!=-1 ? location.href+='checkout' : location.href='shop/checkout'`

Comment: well, yes that would work. but as said, the problem is on the other end

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot.

Instead of writing it inline, write a jQuery/JS onclick event handler to do this.

Example

```
$.("a").click( function() {
    window.location = "/shop/checkout";
));
```